# Counting Based on Conditions

Tags: excel

I have two columns:

```
No. in Class     Class    
1                Class 1
2                Class 1
1                Class 2
2                Class 2
3                Class 2
```

My problem is that I currently have a very large empty 'No. in Class' column that I need to fill in. I could do this by hand, but what I would like to do is count the number of occurrences of a given 'Class', e.g. 'Class 1', and then paste in each cell next to it a count until it reached the total. I have tried to use the `COUNTIF` function, but don't see how I could get the 'Class' as a condition and then paste a value in the column next to it.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is sorted, and your columns are A & B

in A2

`=IFERROR(IF(B2<>B1,1,A1+1),1)`

Copy down as required.